# react js pass url boolean to component to detect, is undefined when checked

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a boolean thru the url for the react js component to use however it keeps coming up undefined. I tried multiple url combination and it has been a guessing game.

my route for the boolean url attribute is

```
<Route path={"http://myurl.com/:showUserInfo"} component={myComponent}>
```

in the myComponent in the render scope

```
const test = this.props.match.showUserInfo
```

test is always undefined.

I tried the following url

```
http://myurl.com/:showUserInfo=false
http://myurl.com/showUserInfo=false
http://myurl.com/showUserInfo={false}
```

I would like to detect the boolean flag and can I get the value?

I tried a few more but no success. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `const test = this.props.match.params.showUserInfo` to read from route.